# jasperreport and JSP use mysql query problem

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports

I use JasperReport 5.5.0 and jsp to connect into MySQL.

It success when my sql query is 
`select * from send`
it can show all data in JasperReport pdf.

But when my sql query is 
`select * from send where name like 'n%'`
it only can show the last `'n%'` row  (but my `'n%'` have 5 rows)

This is my code:

```
<% 
    String sql = "select * from send where name like 'n%' "; 
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    JRDataSource dataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
    File reportFile;
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    byte[] bytes = {0};
    ServletOutputStream outStream ;
    reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("/report/report3.jasper"));
    while(rs.next())
    {
        parameters.put("name",rs.getString("name"));
        parameters.put("youad",rs.getString("youad"));       
        bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), 
parameters,dataSource); 
    }   
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close(); 
    rs.close();              
%>
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `$P{name}` instead of `$F{name}` in the Jasper report. Where `$P{name}` (parameter `name`) will always contain the last value because when you are iterating through the result set and putting the name value into the `parameters` map under the `name` key it will overwrite the previous value.

Another problem is that you are calling `JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf()` in each `while` iteration and it creates PDF for each ResultSet row but only the last PDF bytes will remain (containing the last row from the SQL select).

So you can simply remove whole `while` cycle from the JSP, call `JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf()` only once, define fields for all values you need (`name`, `youad`) in the report template and use them using field `$F{}` syntax instead of parameter. JasperReport will then use all values from the `JRResultSetDataSource` instance.